# How to remove text under TabIcon in react-native-router-flux

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

i can't remove text under TabIcon in TabBar of react-native-router-flux. It is screen of my TabBar:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFBqG.png)

And it is my code of router:

```
const TabBar = ({focused}) => (
    <View>
        <Icon name="search" type="MaterialIcons" style={{fontSize: 28, color: focused ? 'red': 'white'}} />
    </View>
)

export default () => (
    <Router>
        <Scene hideNavBar>

            <Scene key="tabbar" tabs tabBarStyle={{backgroundColor: '#000'}}>

                <Scene key="list" title="Ahlo" component={List} hideNavBar icon={TabBar} />

                <Scene key="search" component={search} hideNavBar icon={TabBar} />

                <Scene key="account" component={account} hideNavBar icon={TabBar} />
            </Scene>

            <Scene key="article" component={article} />

            <Scene key="comment" component={comment} />

            <Scene key="register" component={register} />

            <Scene key="auth" component={auth} />
        </Scene>
    </Router>
)
```

In every tutorials i see that text under TabIcon is missing but i have it. What do i do wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by adding the `showLabel` props to parent or particular child `Scene` to `false`, (By default its value is `true`)

So your tabbar Scene code will be like:

```
<Scene key="tabbar" showLabel={false} tabs tabBarStyle={{backgroundColor: "#000"}}>
       <Scene key="list" component={List} showLabel={false} hideNavBar icon={TabBar} />
       <Scene key="search" component={search} showLabel={false} hideNavBar icon={TabBar} />
       <Scene key="account" component={account} showLabel={false} hideNavBar icon={TabBar} />
</Scene>
```

Hope this will help.